# Does Dreamweaver support inline CSS styles?

Tags: css, dreamweaver

I don't write HTML every day, so DreamWeaver is a useful crutch.  Often I find myself writing content for a site where I have no control over the page header.  I need/want to use some one-off CSS to do some layout, etc.  If I'm not mistaken, the only way I have to do that is to use inline CSS.

DreamWeaver provides nice dialog-box-based support for editing CSS in a stylesheet, but AFAICT, not for inline CSS.  Am I missing something?  Obviously, I can hand-edit - I'm looking for pull-downs, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which version you have but on CS4 if I bring up the properties dialog (Windows->Properties) and then click the CSS button on the left then `<inline style>` is an option on the Targeted Rule dropdown. You can then click Edit Rule to specify the inline CSS you want.

Comment: Thanks - of course, like so many UI things, once you know, it's "how the heck did I miss THAT?!".